# Modify object values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const arr1 = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Dave', tax: 123.34543}
    {id: 2, name: 'John', tax: 3243.12323}
    {id: 3, name: 'Tom', tax: 122.34324}
]
```

And I am trying to round off the tax value, so in the end the array should look like this:

```
[
   {id: 1, name: 'Dave', tax: 123.34}
   {id: 2, name: 'John', tax: 3243.12}
   {id: 3, name: 'Tom', tax: 122.34}
]
```

I tried using the `map` function like so:

`arr1.map(value => Math.round(value.tax * 100)/100);`

but instead of getting a modified array of objects, I get an array with only the result of the `Math.round` which looks like this:
`[ 123.34, 3243.12, 122.34]`

How do I map the array of objects to get the expected result as described above.

Thanks.

Comment: Why your `tax` values are strings(not numbers)?

Comment: do you want a new array with new objects or just the same with mutated props?

Comment: @MohammadUsman My bad. That was typo. Thanks.

Comment: @NinaScholz A new array would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map new objects with the wanted values.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, name: 'Dave', tax: 123.34543 }, { id: 2, name: 'John', tax: 3243.12323 }, { id: 3, name: 'Tom', tax: 122.34324 }],
    result = array.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { tax: Math.round(o.tax * 100) / 100 }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can update `tax` in your `map` function.

See implementation below.

```js
const arr1 = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Dave', tax: '123.34543'},
    {id: 2, name: 'John', tax: '3243.12323'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Tom', tax: '122.34324'},
];

const taxRoundedArray = arr1.map(item => {
  let tax = Math.round(item.tax * 100)/100
  return {
    ...item,
    tax
  }
});

console.log(taxRoundedArray);
```

Comment: This adds an extra `tax` property to each object.

Comment: It shouldn't do. Look at the returned array. As it uses the spread operator it hasn't added another tax property. https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/spread-operator-and-destructuring-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript-2f5578e1252b

Comment: also, just so you are aware, the solution you accepted is more or less the same, but has used Object.assign instead of the spread operator, but they do the same thing.

Comment: Oh I see. I believe I made an error on my end when I was testing your solution.
Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) processes the entry in array and return the processed value. In the attempt, you were only returning the updated tax, however, you will need to return the object. Try following

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Dave', tax: 123.34543},{id: 2, name: 'John', tax: 3243.12323},{id: 3, name: 'Tom', tax: 122.34324}];

const arr2 = arr1.map(({tax, ...rest}) => ({...rest, tax: Math.round(tax * 100)/100}));
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the correct solution, see below:

```
arr1.map(value => {
  value.tax = Math.round(value.tax * 100)/100);
  return value
});
```

You need to return the altered object otherwise it gets overwritten.

Hope this helps

Lloyd

Comment: Ahh I see. Stupid me. Thanks.

Comment: this approach alters the original object, becaus it assigns a new value to `tax`. please look to `arr1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Dave', tax: '123.34543'},
  {id: 2, name: 'John', tax: '3243.12323'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Tom', tax: '122.34324'}
];

const result = arr1.map(user => {
  user.tax = (Math.round(+user.tax * 100) / 100);
  return user;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know what the `+` is used for?

Comment: That is the [Unary plus (+) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to convert `string` into a `number`

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and return each object with a new tax value that has been turned to a floating-point number fixed to two decimal places.

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":1,"name":"Dave","tax":"123.34543"},{"id":2,"name":"John","tax":"3243.12323"},{"id":3,"name":"Tom","tax":"122.34324"}];

const arr2 = arr1.map(obj => {
  const tax = +Number.parseFloat(obj.tax).toFixed(2);
  return { ...obj, tax };
})

console.log(arr2);
```